# Correct way to create new XML file from Adobe Air

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I'm having trouble creating an XML file from Air.  It always seems to have some extra character in front of the first  block in the xml file like this "¥".  This application can read back out of the document, but if i open it with a text editor to make a change and save it, it will no longer open in my application.  Am I doing something wrong when i create this XML file, the whole reason i want to use an XML is so that i can possibly edit it on another computer, or in a text editor, and send it back.  What can i do do make this possible?

Right now I'm creating the XML like this:

```
    var myXML:XML = 

            <motor>
                <type>{motor.type}</type>
                <shopLocation>{motor.shopLocation}</shopLocation>
                <customer>{motor.customer}</customer>
                <tech>{motor.tech}</tech>
                .......
            </motor>;
```

and i'm saving it like this:

```
    protected function fileSave_clickHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            fileName = motorObject.woNum + " - " + motorObject.customer;//default file name
            var dataFile:File =File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(directory + "\\" + fileName);
            dataFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onSave_Handler);
            dataFile.browseForSave("Save Malloy Repair Item");

        }

        protected function onSave_Handler(event:Event):void
        {   var file:File = event.currentTarget as File;
            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
            fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            var motorToXML:MotorObjectToXML = new MotorObjectToXML();
            fs.writeObject(motorToXML.buildMotorObjectToXML(motorObject));
            fs.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try `writeUTFBytes(motorToXML.buildMotorObjectToXML(motorObject).toXMLString())` to write the xml as a string instead of as an object.

Comment: Changing this and the cooresponding load function solved my problem.  Thanks so much for your insight on this problem.